# Kubuntu 16.04 : Software centre search bug

Tags: kubuntu, software-center, 16.04

I installed the new 16.04 kubuntu and I have problem with Discover - Software center. So these are the screen shot that I have made

This is the first look you see that we have wrong aligned text, but the main problem is that we have vlc player, chromium in best rating column:

[image: This is the first look you see that we have wrong aligned text, but the main problem is that we have vlc player, chromium in best rating column.]

And here for example i make search by vlc and nothing appear:

[image: And here for example i make search by vlc and nothing appear]

And this is not only for vlc this behavior is for everything (chromium, gimp and the others) but if they are visible or if i find the application that i want in some of the categories i`m able to install it, so any suggestion why I have this kind of behavior with this software center?

Answer (score 5):

This bug had been reported on Kubuntu/KDE.

I have found that updating it to the latest stable release it fixes the bug on my Kubuntu 16.04.

Here is how I did it. (You can also find more information on the official Kubuntu website)

Updating to Plasma 5.6.4

How to get the update:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade -y
```

Comment: @Pilot6 I just did... and deleted my latest comment the instant you just posted your latest. All is understood now, thanks :)