# Kubuntu 16.04 Discover search bug - Answer!

Tags: kubuntu, search

Because of requiring reputation, I post the answer of this question. To be able to see search results in Discover, open Konsole and type "sudo apt-get install muon". When finish installing, search Muon in KDE start menu. Open Muon package manager, wait to refresh packages and then close. Now open Discover and you're done!!!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please *edit* your question to be an actual question. You can then answer your own question by putting the answer in the answer space.

Comment: This is effectively a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/q/761824/25036 (and an additional answer to that question will be significantly different from the one that's already there).