# Kubuntu 16.04 Discover Software center (muon)

Tags: kubuntu, software-center, muon-package-manager

Just installed Kubuntu and updated softwares etc via muon.  Muon is opening but I'm not able to view softwares or seach for one. Blank screen. When searching via category also blank (no apps viewing).  What should I do?

Comment: Make sure it's fully updated in command line, reboot and try again: `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade`

Comment: I think I'm using the latest version , tried the command but still not working .

Answer (score 0):

I think this answer from here could help [Kubuntu 16.04 : Software centre search bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761824/kubuntu-16-04-software-centre-search-bug/788878#answer-788878)

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade -y
```